# Scripting: How to change objects mode and then revert back to previous mode

Tags: scripting

In my script I'm trying to set mode to a certain type, but when I'm done with whatever I'm doing I would like to set back the previous mode it was in.

Example: Scene is in EDIT mode, but I need OBJECT mode, but then when I'm done I want to go in to EDIT mode back since it was initial mode.

My code goes:

```
originalMode = bpy.ops.object.mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

...

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=originalMode)
```

And I get this error:

```
  ... File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 189, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties:  expected a string enum, not BPyOpsSubModOp
```

I don't know how to convert this back to 'EDIT' string to set the mode...
Hlp please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that is this: `bpy.ops.object.mode` current mode is here: `bpy.context.mode`

Save current mode:

```
returnto=False
if(context.mode!='OBJECT'):
    returnto=context.mode
```

Return to edit mode:

```
if(returnto):
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=returnto)
```

[bpy.context.mode](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_release/bpy.context.html#bpy.context.mode)